# how to override user value and save into another table in django

Tags: python, django

```
     I have a one model Product which have field location  and 1 another model name is Inventory movement in which product is foreign key. 
inventory movement model
            product_id=models.ForeignKey(Product)
            from_location = models.CharField("from location",max_length=30) 
            to_location=models.CharField("Locatiion",max_length=30)       
            user=models.CharField("Supervised By",max_length=50)
            remarks=models.CharField("Remarks",max_length=50) 
Product model. 
     product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
        product_name=models.CharField("Product Name",max_length=50)
        location=models.CharField("Location",max_length=30)
```

firstly data is present in product model and now i want if user want to change the product location is maintain by inventory movement form. 
        now when user enter a to_location field in inventory from is also override the product.location field how can i do this ?

Comment: This seems to be your first question. Edit it and be clear what you are asking. Provide both models and what you expect with a code example.

Comment: provide your `models.py` in **readable** form